# Webform nodeview content & form separation

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

**Can anyone offer any insight into how I can show the body content and the form of the same webform node on separate pages?**

My Drupal site has webform nodes which all have alot of body content and equally long forms. As a result, the entire combination seems complex and not very user friendly.

I need to find a way to keep both aspects associated to the same node but create distinct viewing areas for each half.

ps: Apologies if there is a module for this. I googled very quickly and may have missed it.

Answer (score 1):

[Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) can reorganize your whole node layout. you can add views, block and even custom code.

[fieldgroup](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) you can split large forms or views in the manage display section of your content type.

hope it helps

PR